# ConnectionError using elasticsearch npm package when switching form localhost to AWS?

Tags: elasticsearch

I can successfully index a document on localhost using the elasticsearch npm package.

```
const elasticSearchClient = new Client({
  node:
    "http://localhost:9200"
});
await elasticSearchClient.index({
  index: "twitter",
  body: {
    user: "kimchy",
    post_date: "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
    message: "trying out Elasticsearch"
  }
});
```

I can successfully index a document on AWS using curl

```
curl -X POST "https://...eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com/twitter/_doc/?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "user" : "kimchy",
    "post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
    "message" : "trying out Elasticsearch"
}
```

But when I try to index a document on AWS using the npm package I get a `ConnectionError`:

```
const elasticSearchClient = new Client({
  node:
    "https://...eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com"
});
await elasticSearchClient.index({
  index: "twitter",
  body: {
    user: "kimchy",
    post_date: "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
    message: "trying out Elasticsearch"
  }
});

{ ConnectionError: connect ENETUNREACH [ip-address]
    at onResponse (/home/[user]/dev/Other/couch-transformer/node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/Transport.js:205:13)
    at ClientRequest.request.on.err (/home/[user]/dev/Other/couch-transformer/node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/Connection.js:98:9)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)   name: 'ConnectionError',   meta:    { body: null,
     statusCode: null,
     headers: null,
     warnings: null,
     meta:
      { context: null,
        request: [Object],
        name: 'elasticsearch-js',
        connection: [Object],
        attempts: 3,
        aborted: false } } }
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Are you sure about the port? Can you reach `...eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com` simply in a terminal via curl ?

Comment: @Val: I see no information about the port on AWS, so I haven't specified port in the url. I can reach it via curl. I can index documents and do everything I want. When using the npm package I get 'ConnectionError' on any action, even on client.info()

Comment: Hmm, I think you need to also set the [`ssl` configuration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/auth-reference.html#_ssl_configuration) in your client configuration since your AWS URL is in https. You might also want to try a client wrapper: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-elasticsearch-client